# Select 1 column when DF has 2 similar column names in R

Tags: r, grepl

I have 2 problems. First, I have datasets with 2 column names that are similar. I want to select the first one and not use the second one. The numeric values in the column names are the serial number of the sensor and can vary and they can be in various columns.

How can I select the first column name of the 2 so I can plot it or use it in calculations?

How can I recover those long column names so I can use them? For example how to I get "Depth_456" to use in depthmax2 with out typing it in or making a subset named depth. The problem is the numeric value which is the serial number of the sensor and it changes from instrument to instrument and dataset to dataset.  I am trying to write generic code that will work on all the different instruments.

**My Data**

```
df1 <- data.frame(Sal_224 = 1:8, Temp_696 = 1:8, Depth_456 = 1:8, Temp_654 = 8:15)
df2<-data.frame(sapply(df1, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x))))

temp<- df2[grep("Temp", names(df2), value=TRUE)]
depth<- df2[grep("Depth", names(df2), value=TRUE)]

depthmax<- max(depth, na.rm = TRUE)
depthmax2<- max(df2$"Depth_456", na.rm = TRUE)
```

This doesn't work

```
depthmax2<- max(df2$grep("Depth", names(df2), value=TRUE), na.rm = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need `[[` instead of `$`.

```
max(df2[[ grep("Depth", names(df2), value=TRUE)]], na.rm = TRUE)
#[1] 8
```

Or another option is `startsWith`

```
max(df2[[names(df2)[startsWith(names(df2), "Depth")]]], na.rm = TRUE)
#[1] 8
```

Also, `max` works on a vector.  If there are more than one match, we may have to loop over and get the `max`

```
sapply(df2[ grep("Depth", names(df2), value=TRUE)], max, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: This works great with the depth; however, I realize I wasn't clear about my problem with temp which returns 8 objects and 2 variables. I want to use just the first temp variable and not the second. So how do I separate them so I can just use the first one - Temp_696? Note: the number at the end of temp varies depending on which instrument the data-set came from.  @akrun

Comment: @seaviper Do you need `max(df2[[grep("Temp", names(df2), value=TRUE)[1]]], na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: Your first solution works for depth but I also needed to figure out how to get the first temp which when you use grep it returns 2 temp's . I think the simplistic approach may be the best using temp1<- temp[1] @akrun

Comment: I got it by adding [1] to the end of temp<- df2[grep("Temp", names(df2), value=TRUE)] [1]. Now I just have to figure out what and why it did it. Thanks @akrun